# What does "org.hibernate.type.CollectionType : Created collection wrapper" means?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading, one-to-many, many-to-one

LazyLoading does not seem to work in my app and I don't why.

I have entities which are related like below:

```
public class Participant {
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "participant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private Set<RequestProduct>                  requestProducts;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "participant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private Set<ParticipantRank>                 participantRanks;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "participant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private Set<RequestProductParticipant>       requestProductParticipants;
}
```

And

```
public class RequestProduct {
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String identifier;       

  @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
  private Participant participant;
}
```

And the repository:

```
public interface RequestProductRepository extends JpaRepository<RequestProduct, Long> { 

 Optional<RequestProduct> findByIdentifier( String identifier );
}
```

And the service method:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class ServiceImpl {
   private RequestProductRepository repo;

   public void modifyRequestProduct(String identifier){ 
    //THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    Optional<RequestProduct> product = repo.findByIdentifier( identifier );
  }
}
```

When I call the `findByIdentifier` method, it seems like all data are loaded. I have these stacktrace:

```
[ taskExecutor-7] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [org.module.module.models.Participant.requestProducts#1]
[ taskExecutor-7] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [org.module.module.models.Participant.participantRanks#1]
[ taskExecutor-7] org.hibernate.type.CollectionType        : Created collection wrapper: [org.module.module.models.Participant.requestProductParticipants#1]
```

And 3 big `select` queries loading all data from each of the 3 tables are invoked. What is going on?
Is it normal?

Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem and found a solution. The reason this is occurring is because the collection is of type **Set**. Java by default tries checks if an object already exists in the set by checking if ALL its properties are equal to the counter object so it will fetch all your participant collections.

I fixed this by overriding the **equals** and **hash** methods for my models and only compared them using the ID as such:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    RequestProduct requestProduct = (RequestProduct) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, requestProduct.id);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}
```

Sorry for being almost a year late =/